# Modifing titanium slider

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

The default titanium slider only allows you to have one pin on it.

How could you modify it, so that it accepts a range of values. Such as age range?

Cheers.

UPDATE (after installing module):

```
// Double Slider example

var tidoubleslider = require('com.semanticpress.tidoubleslider');

var dSlider = tidoubleslider.createSlider({
    top: 40,
    height: 50,
    width: 280,
    leftTrackImage:'left2.png',
    highlightedLeftTrackImage:'highlightedLeft2.png',
    disabledLeftTrackImage:'disabledLeft2.png',
    centerTrackImage:'center2.png',
    highlightedCenterTrackImage:'highlightedCenter2.png',
    disabledCenterTrackImage:'disabledCenter2.png',
    rightTrackImage:'right2.png',
    highlightedRightTrackImage:'highlightedRight2.png',
    disabledRightTrackImage:'disabledRight2.png',
    leftThumbImage:'thumb.png',
    highlightedLeftThumbImage:'highlightedThumb.png',
    disabledLeftThumbImage:'disabledThumb.png',
    rightThumbImage:'thumb.png',
    highlightedRightThumbImage:'highlightedThumb.png',
    disabledRightThumbImage:'disabledThumb.png',
    min:0,
    max:50,
    leftValue:25,
    rightValue:50,
    enabled: true
});
$.ageSliderView.add(dSlider);

var leftLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    top:30,
    left:20,
    width:100,
    height: 20,
    color:'black',
    text:dSlider.leftValue
});
$.ageSliderView.add(leftLabel);

var rightLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    top:30,
    right:20,
    width:100,
    height: 20,
    color:'black',
    text:dSlider.rightValue,
    textAlign:'right'
});
$.ageSliderView.add(rightLabel);

dSlider.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    if (typeof e.value !== 'undefined') {
        if (e.thumbIndex === 0) {
            leftLabel.text = e.value.toFixed(1);
            leftLabel.color = 'red';
        }
        else {
            rightLabel.text = e.value.toFixed(1);
            rightLabel.color = 'red';
        }
    }
    else {
        leftLabel.color = 'gray';
        rightLabel.color = 'gray';
    }
});

dSlider.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.thumbIndex === 0) {
        leftLabel.text = e.value.toFixed(1);
    }
    else {
        rightLabel.text = e.value.toFixed(1);
    }
});

dSlider.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    if (typeof e.value !== 'undefined') {
        if (e.thumbIndex === 0) {
            leftLabel.text = e.value.toFixed(1);
            leftLabel.color = 'black';
        }
        else {
            rightLabel.text = e.value.toFixed(1);
            rightLabel.color = 'black';
        }
    }
    else {
        leftLabel.color = 'black';
        rightLabel.color = 'black';
    }
});
```

The slider does not appear on the screen. I guess it is because the slider images are missing?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.The slider With raning option in titanium

https://github.com/tzmartin/Ti-Double-Slider/tree/master/dist

Thanks

Comment: thanks! How do I install and use it - there doesn't seem to be any read me instructions with it. Thanks again.

Comment: Read this guid for installing module  http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Using_a_Module

Comment: hi updated my original post. Got the module installed, but the slider does not appear in the window. See OP for the problem, cheers.